# How to automate the process of generating non-qualified electronic signatures?

Tags: active-directory, x509certificate, windows-server

Good afternoon. A rather difficult question for me has arisen.
A “Certification Authority (local)” Active Directory has been created on the server. When the user's electronic signature certificate expires, he needs to contact a support worker and request the issuance of a new certificate. The service employee logs into the Microsoft Certificate Authority portal and subsequently receives a new certificate. Since there are many users, it takes official time. Is it possible to somehow automatically issue certificates to users when the previous ones expire?

I tried to do this through powershell but nothing works. We need a way in which employees do not need to do anything themselves, only receive notifications about successful completion